# TreeView loses style on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have 2 selects and treeview.
TreeView rebuilds when any of selects are changed.

But treeview looses all styling on postback when click treeview node.
I wonder how to keep treeView styles?

Comment: How are you setting the styles? From codebehind, from javascript? Using css?

Comment: problem solved guys, ty all for interest. Styles applied from codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have forgotten the EnableViewState property

treeview1.EnableViewState = True

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx